Comparing the data with Visual Studio
as my title says, I am trying to compare a .sql file and database objects from my SSMS database using Visual Studio (Schema Compare option). For example, I added a basic CREATE TABLE statement to my .sql file and executed it in my database. There is no difference shown in Visual Studio, which is expected. When I click on the .sql file in Visual Studio, I also get a preview of the table. However, when I add one more CREATE TABLE statement to my .sql file and also execute it in my database, a difference is shown, even though all the queries are the same in the .sql file and my database after execution. Additionally, when I click on the .sql file to get a preview in Visual Studio, there is none—it only shows the CREATE TABLE queries, but not the table preview like before when there was just one table.
So, my question is: Is it possible to do a schema compare with multiple CREATE TABLE queries in a single .sql file, or do I need to put each CREATE TABLE statement in a separate file?

"do I need to put each CREATE TABLE statement in a separate file" I generally find its best practice anyway, especially if you are planning to put this into version control software (which presumably you are). Otherwise a change to one table results in a change to "all" your tables, as they're all in one big script.

ok thank you for your help !!
